# is this error of amadeus api from my code?

Tags: api, amadeus

hello amadeus users i'm facing this problem

i'm amadeus beginner

when i started to use amadues sandbox php client

the system worked for me for about an hour then this error appeared from yesterday

this error appears in php and in site page

is this system related to my code or my api or general network failure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our API platform is currently going through a maintenance check. Some APIs may get disrupted during that time. The platform will be available again in a short time.

Comment: Okay , thank you . 
does it will take long time for examples as week or it will work shortly in hours ?

Comment: It is back up and running,